# How to unit test jQuery keyboard events?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, events, keyboard-events, qunit

Is there a way to test JavaScript keyboard event handlers (for `keypress`, `keyup`, `keydown` events)?

I know I can declare event handlers like this:

```
function keyUpEvHandler(e) {
    ... // code here
}

$('#myId').keyup(keyUpEvHandler);
```

and then just run this function in unit tests, but I will have to prepare event argument object to be the same as passed when actual key is pressed:

```
var e = {keyCode: 70, ...};
```

Is there any way to trigger this event and pass key code as an argument or something similar? Unfortunately [jQuery trigger() docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) doesn't cover keyboard events.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary data through the event object.

The docs:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("logged");
event.user = "foo";
event.pass = "bar";
$("body").trigger(event);
```

What you can do:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("keyup");
event.keyCode = 72;
$(".selector").trigger(event);
```

This way, the event passed to the handler(s) will have the `keyCode` set to whatever you want.

Comment: Good answer, but this does not seem to work with triggerEvent(), which is more useful when testing for the return value of a handler.